# Jquery Selector Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

basically I'm trying to get #toggle_box to slide down using Jquery, the code below works if I'm just using document.body as the selector however it doesn't seem to work when #toggle is the selector! Any ideas why?

```
<html>
<head>

<title>JQuery Testage</title>
<style>
#toggle_box {
 display: none;
}
#toggle {
 background-color: #FFF000;
 border: solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#toggle").click(function () {
 if ($("#toggle_box").is(":hidden")) {
 $("#toggle_box").slideDown("slow");
 } else {
 $("#toggle_box").hide();
 }
 });
</script>

<div id="toggle">Toggle</div>

<div id="toggle_box">This should silde using the Jquery library 1.4.2</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function () {
    if ($("#toggle_box").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#toggle_box").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
      $("#toggle_box").hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that the javascript is loaded and executed before the `toggle_box` element is loaded. It works for the document `body` as that **is** loaded before the javascript.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it wasn't working, stupid mistake to be making really! :P

Comment: @Sean You'll probably find that 99% of us make the same mistake at some point. What's important is not the making of the mistake but learning from it :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the click handler a [`$(document).ready(...`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) wrap, and it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     // your click handler and anything else that
     // should run when the DOM is ready

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the DOM isn't ready yet?
Try wrapping your script in the following piece of code:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

That's a short code for `$(document).ready(function(){ ...});` and may just be what's missing?